# Is it possible to use on Android N the backend with certificate with support only TLS 1.0?

Tags: android, ssl, https

I have an app with targetSdkVersion 23 but when launched on Android N (apiLevel 24) all connections to backend raise an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)`
<...>
Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
    ... 23 more
Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7ffeec27f540: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000f3:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_CURVE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1205 0x7ffee9cef70a:0x00000000)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7ffeec27f540: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000f3:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_CURVE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1205 0x7ffee9cef70a:0x00000000)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7ffeec27f540: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000f3:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_CURVE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1205 0x7ffee9cef70a:0x00000000)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 22 more
```

My backend certificate supports only TLSv1 protocol. Is this a problem for Android N?

**Edited 1:**
Changing targetSdkVersion to 24 gives me same result.

**Edited 2:**
Our target URL is https://med.firecracker.me/

Comment: You have truncated the Stacktrace, the relevant inner exception (with the exception text) is missing.

Comment: I would first try changing the targetSdkVersion to 24 and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Changing targetSdkVersion to 24 gives me same result.

Comment: Full stacktrace added. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "TLSv1" certificate. There are X.509 certificates which can be used for authentication within several TLS versions, including SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.2... As for the error itself: "WRONG_CURVE" could give a clue but one would probably need to know the target URL for better help. My guess is that the server does not work as expected when used with the newer TLS stack of Android N which might be a bug in the server or in Android.

Comment: "need to know the target URL for better help" --

Our target URL is `https://med.firecracker.me/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the certificate has been updated to support TLS 1.2.